# why the table tag without width can be centered

Tags: css

I'm reading a trick to center element. It said if you want to center the ul element what has no width, a approach is to put it inside a table and set table margin left/right to auto. But the table element itself has no width, why the table can be centered?..

```css
table{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just a side note, you can achieve this without additional HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/dpz6rae2/

Comment: I don't see how this trick can apply to the `ul` element.  It's certainly not centered here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4pca9fv4/

Comment: @RickHitchcock If you add a border to the table, you will see that the table is centered.  Keep in mind that the `ul` has default margins and padding that makes it appear that the content is not centered. See http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/4pca9fv4/1/

Comment: Thanks, I thought the trick was how to "center the ul element."  If we're talking about the bullet point circles specifically, then I suppose it's centered.

Comment: @RickHitchcock The OP seemed to be asking about why the table with its default width setting can be centered with left/right margin of 0. Centering a `ul` is slightly different because the default width for `ul` is 100%, not shrink-to-fit.

Comment: Right, I was addressing the "trick" for centering `ul` elements rather than the OP's question regarding centering the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `table` is a block level element and by default, it has a width of `auto`, which means that it will compute a width that shrinks-to-fit the content.  If the content leads to a width that is less than 100% of the table's containing block, then setting the left/right margin to auto will center the table within the containing block.

If you specify a width to the table, centering with `margin: 0 auto` will also work as long as the specified width is less than that of the containing block.

**To Center the UL Without Using a Table**

Here are two examples.  In the first, I specify a width to the `ul`.  In the second, I specify `display: table` which makes the `ul` behave like a table element instead of a block element.

```css
.ex1 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.ex2 {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<h3>Example 1 - Specify a width</h3>
<ul class="ex1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>  

<h3>Example 2 - Use a CSS table</h3>
<ul class="ex2">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. But why can't I just put the ul inside a div, and set div margin left/right to auto? The div in question is also a block level element and it will compute it's width against it's content.

Comment: The default width for a `ul` is 100% of the width of the containing block, therefore left/right margin of auto does not have a visible effect.  If you set the width of the `ul` to 50% (or similar), you will see the effect.

Comment: your explanation is very clear. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if you are satisfied and welcome to SO!

Comment: This is not quite correct. The default specified width for ul is "auto" not 100%. If it were 100%, and `width:auto` made the element shrink-to-fit, then assigning `width:auto;margin:0 auto` to the ul would centre it, but it doesn't. More generally, a width of "auto" on a block level element does not make it shrink-to-fit. `display:table` elements have their own width sizing rules that override the standard block-level behaviour, to the effect of being shrink-to-fit for `width:auto`.

Comment: @Alohci You are right in saying that for `ul`, the default width is `auto` because it is a block level, non-replaced element, and in this case, the width of `ul` will take up the width of the containing block subject to any constraints by margins and padding (in this sense, auto means 100%; I was taking some liberty with the wording).  Your statement regarding  `table` is correct, specifically for the case of `table-layout: auto`, which uses the automatic table layout algorithm.  Your comment does help to clarify things, which will be appreciated by others who may read the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The table's width as a block level element expands to fit the content (an unordered list won't).

As an alternative to putting the `ul` in a table which you really shouldn't do because it's not semantic (unless you actually want a table of course!), you can set `ul {text-align: center}` and `ul li {display: block}`

```css
ul {
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you sir, you are right. What I dont understand in my sample code is why I cannot just put the ul inside a div, but must be inside a table. why it won't be centered if in a  div?..